# Quais as camadas e nomes de pastas para organizar os projetos?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern

Tenho uma aplicação que precisará ser desenvolvida da seguinte forma:

- Aplicação Web (provavelmente MVC)
- Aplicação Servidora Web (WCF - Rodará no IIS)
- Aplicação Servidora Cliente (WCF Windows Services)
- Aplicação Cliente (WPF), também existem aplicações Delphi XE3

A aplicação Web será hospedada juntamente com a Aplicação WCF.

A aplicação Servidora Cliente será uma Aplicação Servidora Web também (WCF Windows Service) que será consumida pela aplicação Cliente (WPF) e também por outros programas em Delphi já existente.

Isso é para integrar a Matriz com as Filiais.

Tanto as aplicações Cliente e a Aplicação Servidora Cliente (WCF Windows Service) poderão se comunicar com a Aplicação Servidora Web (WCF no IIS).

Quais as práticas adequadas para organizar as camadas desses projetos e as pastas que separam os projetos?

Até o momento pensei em criar uma camada modelo, que representará minhas tabelas do banco de dados.

Não usarei ORM, e sim DAO.

Comment: Savero, seja bem vindo ao site. Sua pergunta é extremamente complexa, e já lhe digo, nenhuma das respostas aqui encontrada, responderá sua pergunta. Para arquitetar seu projeto precisa-se conhecer muito mais sobre o projeto. Não existe uma regra de arquitetura. Existem algumas comuns, mas não significa que irá servir 100% para seu projeto. Outra coisa, você confundiu ORM com DAO, DAO é um pattern, ORM é um framework para mepar suas classes com su banco de dados. Boa sorte

Comment: Oi Rod, obrigado! Sei o que é ORM. É que ao ter-se um ORM, não tem-se DAO, não é? O que mais eu preciso informar?

Comment: Severo, você pode implementar DAO com um ORM. DAO dentre suas "especificações" implementa fabricas abstratas. Assim, por exemplo, em um determinado contexto pode solicitar que sejam instanciadas "entidades" de ORMs diferentes. Ou ainda, de implementações para formatos específicos, como "entidades" que gerenciam um set de arquivos servindo banco de dados XML. Portanto, sim, você pode implementar DAO e usar ORM em conjunto.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que sua pergunta resume-se a:

**Quais as práticas adequadas para organizar as camadas desses projetos e as pastas que separam os projetos?**

Quebrando sua pergunta em duas partes:

**Quais as práticas adequadas para organizar as camadas desses projetos?**

É preciso entender o por quê usamos camadas. Dentre as várias razões, destaco algumas:

Para abaixar o acoplamento entre componentes(projetos, dlls, etc) e aumentar a coesão. (se estas palavras não fazem sentido para você, começe por este link [Padrões na prática -Coesão e acoplamento](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/cc947917.aspx)

Além disso, desenhar camadas entre os componentes ajuda a manter as responsabilidades separadas de forma correta, ou seja, você mantem perto coisas que mudam pela mesma razão. (nada de escrever sql dentro do controller do mvc, por exemplo).

Por último e mais importante, ao mencionar práticas adequadas a única coisa que eu posso te afirmar com toda certeza é que um bom design é sempre desacoplado. Ou seja, não faça com que sua aplicação seja totalmente dependente do WCF, ou do MVC, separe a sua camada de regra de negócio e proteja ela dessas dependências usando abstrações). Um pequeno artigo que mostra um pouco sobre isso [Hexagonal Architecture (Ports and Adapters)](http://elemarjr.net/2014/01/03/hexagonal-architecture-ports-and-adapters/)

Por último:

**e as pastas que separam os projetos?**

Essa uma decisão inteiramente do seu time, no Visual Studio por exemplo, ao criar uma pasta na solução ele nem mesmo cria ela no disco, é apenas uma organização visual. Seja significativo, escolha bons nomes que demonstram sua intenção.

Eu poderia discutir sobre esse assunto por muito mais tempo, mas acho que isso envolve o risco de eu te confundir mais ainda, acho que você precisa segmentar melhor sua pergunta, dessa forma fica mais fácil atacar os problemas separados, sem ser genérico demais.

Se você quiser entender melhor o que são camadas e como dar bons nomes, seguem dois links:

[Camadas?](http://chegadegambiarra.com/2014/09/26/162/)
[Código Limpo - Nomes](http://chegadegambiarra.com/2014/07/07/codigo-limpo-nomes/)

Quanto a discussão sobre ORM e DAO, você pode pensar sim, que o objeto de acesso à dados é o mesmo usado pela ORM para fazer a interação com o banco, logo eles não são exclusivos. Segue um link do SO em inglês mais explicativo: [DAO vs ORM(hibernate) pattern [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037251/dao-vs-ormhibernate-pattern)